# Logic at including of cpp classes in objective c project

Tags: c++, ios, include

I am dealing with this now for some time, and just can't get the point.

I have an ios project in xcode.
I added some cpp classes and made them end *.mm.
Now i have one main class, let's call it PARENT,
and 4 other classes, let's call them CHILDREN.

Now in every CHILDREN class i have a member:

```
PARENT *parentInstanz;
```

And in the constructor of the parent i do something like:

```
this->CHILDREN_A = new CHILDREN();
this->CHILDREN_A->parentInstanz = this;
```

This works so far.
But when i try to access this->parentInstanz->xyz  in a CHILD class i always get: 
member access to incomplete type PARENT.

All my classes are wrapped with something like:

```
#ifndef PARENT
#define PARENT
.....
#endif PARENT
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Might want to look through http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t291181-what-is-incomplete-type-compiler-error.html and see how it applies to your code.

Comment: hi, this was not the solution, but it pointed me the right way .. so i solvedit, thanx !!

Comment: That's good to hear. You can edit your question to include the answer, or answer your own question so others that run into this situation have something to go on too :).

Answer (score 0):

i solved it.
the solution was to do the CHILD CLASS def in the Parent Header.

```
class CHILD_A
class CHILD_B
```

thanx !